# Vector space and linear operator

Tags: linear-transformations

> If $V$ be a vector space and $T$ is a linear operator on $V$ and of
>   $W$ is a subspace of $V$, then $W$ is invariant under $T$ if and only
>   if $\beta$ is the element of $T$ implies
>
> (a) $T(\beta) = 0$
>   (b) $T(\beta)$ is the element of $W$
>   (c) $T(\beta)= (\beta)$
>   (d) None of these

Comment: "$\,\beta\;$ is the element of $\;T\;$ ..."? What does this mean? Perhaps you meant "For **any** element $\;\beta\in W\;$ it implies that..." ?

Comment: "$T(\beta) = (\beta)$" looks weird too.

Answer (score 1):

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace), $W$ is an invariant subspace of $T$ if $T(W)\subseteq W$ and this means that for any vector $ \beta \in W \Rightarrow T(\beta)\in W$.